# Returns the ASCII value as an integer in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to get the Ascii value of character but I'm a bit clueless

So far I've found

```
 Character.getNumericValue
```

But when I read the documentation it says

> Returns the int value that the specified Unicode character

In php I used to use ord(string String)

So will Character.getNumericValue do for me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you have to do is cast `(int) c`, where `c` is your `char` (i.e. character).

Comment: Thanks alot, valuable help :)